# Will install_requires in setuptools work without explicit yocto-recipe for certain packages

Tags: python, yocto, python-packaging

I have a python3 application and want to create a yocto-recipe for the same. The application depends mainly on:

1. `pyserial`
2. `influxdb-python`
3. `pynmea2`

`pynmea2` and `influxdb-python` are not available in the `meta-python` layer.

I have a `setup.py` which has the flag `install_requires`

```
 install_requires = ['pynmea2', 'pyserial', 'influxdb-python']
```

I have found a [repository which provides a basic example for creating python based yocto-recipes](https://github.com/yoctocookbook/meta-custom/blob/master/recipes-python/python-helloworld/python-helloworld_1.0.bb)

but it does not mention any dependencies. Will there be any problem by mentioning `install_requires` and not having those dependencies as recipes?

P.S.
[My Repo](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/gpsinflux)

Comment: As far as Yocto is concerned, it will be fine in compiling it without the required files. But producing the final rootfs needs all the runtime dependencies. If none of your recipes defined this as RDEPENDS on, then you will face run time errors saying missing modules. So it is always best practise to specify RDEPENDS and DEPENDS accordingly for every recipe.

Comment: @Parthiban and for all the packages not available via Yocto? Should I use `devtool` to build them locally? e.g. `pynmea2` and `influxdb-python`?

Comment: If not present, create new in your private layer and add it. If you believe it can be used by anyone in community, push it as patch to meta-python

Comment: You can also check in mailing list or #oe IRC

Comment: @Parthiban Can I fill the `RDEPENDS_${PN}` as the packages mentioned in the `requirements.txt`?